# Building Paths and Areas in a Database from Coordinates (illustrated)

Tags: sql, spatial

I am trying to develop a map showing the amount of air traffic near to airports.
I'm using ADS-B data. Many modern planes have ADS-B transmitters which broadcast their posistion and altitude, amoungst other parameters. I want to collect the data from hundreds, thousands of flights and produce a dataset detailing noise nuisence.

So, I have rows in my database like so

```
ID,  Lat,  Long,  Time
 1, 40.1,  03.1, 12:00
 2, 40.5,  03.5, 12:01
 3, 40.1,  03.9, 12:02
```

This represents a plane flying across the grid, as shown here.[image]

And here is some real life data.[image] The different colours of the squares indicate the number of times a plane flew within their bounds.

This is the end of my current solution - hereafter follows the problem I think I have, and how I think I might solve it.

But of course the plane flew a path - these records in my database just represent snapshots. Infact the plane flew a path, which we can assume was a straight line. [image]

Because the application doesn't require high degrees of accuracy, we can calculate where the plane would have been every 100m or so along it's journey. Further more, I can now say that the plane crossed every one of these grid squares, and deposited a token into it.

[image] But what about the adjacent squares? The plane didn't fly through their bounds, but they still should be recorded.

[image]
A better solution would be to create some sort of polygon, the width of which might be adjusted by the height and size of the plane.

[image]
And then I could map several paths over each other. To illustrate my point I've used transparancies. As several flights pass over an area the colour becomes darker, indicating this area has more flight noise.

[image]

My question is: what methods should I be using/researching to get to this point? My (basic) understanding of a database is as rows of records. I can draw my problem, but I can't get to how I should be turning it into a computational process.